# How to inject service into imported service Nestjs

Tags: nestjs

I have custom module `AuthModule` with `AuthService`, `AuthController` with routes and so on, that work fine, and want to share this module between several projects as a package. The questions is how to extend imported `AuthService` from this package and how to inject in it additional services?

**More details**

Into my custom `AuthService`, that I want to place in package, is injected class `UserService`, that by default gets from the database some `User` data and return it to client side . I need to inject into `AuthService` another, for example `ProfileService` from application, that get from database `User` extra data. The aim is to merge `User` main data and `User` extra data, and return this bunch to client

Comment: More context. Maybe, part of codes. What type of Auth: JWT or Bearer?

Comment: Forgot to clarify that AuthModule is custom, and in this case type does not matter, because it is abstract. The main question is how to inject some application service into another service imported from package

Answer (score 6):

I don't see really the need for a Dynamic Module here.

Indeed, only is needed that the service you want to inject into other entity managed by NestJs, is exported from your AuthModule, and AuthModule imported in the Module you want other entities have injected your AuthService.

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { AuthService } from './AuthService'

@Module({
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    // ... others
  ],
  exports: [
    AuthService
  ]
})
export class CommonModule {}
```

Then in your dependent class (let's say another Controller, but could be anything like a GraphQL Resolver, Interceptor, or whatever), you declare the dependency on AuthService.

```js
import { AuthService } from '../auth/AuthService'
import { Dependencies } from '@nestjs/common'

@Dependencies(AuthService)
export class DependentController {
  constructor (authService) {
    this.authService = authService
  }
}
```

Finally, in order to the AuthService be available to the dependent controller, it has to be imported in the same Module that controller is provided.

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { CommonModule } from '../auth/CommonModule'
import { DependentController } from './controller/DependentController'

@Module({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    // ...others
  ],
  providers: [
    DependentController,
    // ...others
  ]
})
export class ControllerModule {}
```

I understand that the syntax could be shorter and without using Dependencies decorator in typescript, however the core of the matter is exporting the shared Service from the Module it is provided, then importing that module into the Module other classes that require it.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the use cases [Dynamic Modules](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules) have been created for.

```js
import { Module, DynamicModule } from '@nestjs/common';
import { createDatabaseProviders } from './database.providers';
import { Connection } from './connection.provider';

@Module({
  providers: [Connection],
})
export class DatabaseModule {
  static forRoot(entities = [], options?): DynamicModule {
    const providers = createDatabaseProviders(options, entities);
    return {
      module: DatabaseModule,
      providers: providers,
      exports: providers,
    };
  }
}
```

In this example, see how `providers` are given (dynamically) to the result module.

Your package should follow the same pattern: expose a static method which allows building a `DynamicModule`, so you can resolve your other services (internal or external) as you want (building your own array of `providers`).

Comment: In my case I have to wrap all Module into function, then to pass my service thru arguments. something like this:


`
//app.js
import_{createAuthModule} from 'mypackage';
import {ProfileService} from '../../modules/profile'

const AuthModule = createAuthModule(ProfileService);
`

But this is not an elegant solution

Comment: I was thinking about something closer to `YourModule.createDynamically(...)`
But you won't be able to get closer to anything more elegant than a `DynamicModule`. Your approach might be invalid, in a first place. A module is supposed to be self-sufficient and/or embeds its own dependencies. If you wanna allow it to be open-ended, then you have to accept that it requires you to provide the correct dependencies.

Good luck and have fun using Nest!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using GraphQL and my resolver is decorated with `@Resolver()`,
so I had to **not** use `@Dependencies` (since I got a TypeError, that my functions are not functions).

I exported my service:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { UserResolver } from './user.resolver';

@Module({
  providers: [UserResolver, UserService],
  exports: [UserService], //This line is new
})
export class UserModule {}
```

Then, I imported it in the other module:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { IngredientService } from './ingredient.service';
import { IngredientResolver } from './ingredient.resolver';
import { UserModule } from 'src/user/user.module';  //This line is new

@Module({
  providers: [IngredientResolver, IngredientService],
  imports: [UserModule], //This line is new
})
export class IngredientModule {}
```

Then, in my resolver, I added it in the constructor:

```
import { UserService } from 'src/user/user.service'; //This line is new

@Resolver(() => Ingredient)
export class IngredientResolver {
  constructor(
    private readonly ingredientService: IngredientService,
    private readonly userService: UserService, //This line is new
  ) {}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33495675)